# Ceiling fan to run on UPS ONLY

Tags: switching-regulator, ups

I have my room typically connected on a UPS.

During a power failure, the devices on the lighting line (5 A) are powered by the UPS.

I have an air conditioner installed in my room which is on the heating line (15 A), which is isolated from the lighting line. This means that during power failure, only the devices connected on the lighting line will operate (If ON) on the UPS.

My problem is as follows: during normal conditions, my air conditioner is ON when switched ON. During power failure, however, the air conditioner goes OFF. I then have to wake up in the middle of the night to turn on the ceiling fan.

The only other option to this is to have both the air conditioner as well as the ceiling fan running simultaneously so that there is no disruption in air circulation during a power outage.

I need a solution wherein I can automatically turn ON the ceiling fan (on UPS), when the air conditioner goes OFF during a power outage and then revert back to the original state of air conditioner ON and ceiling fan OFF when the power comes back ON.

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! I tried to get though the wall of text. Can you summarize it in a truth table?

Comment: I have edited your question to put paragraph breaks where they seem to belong.  Please _review my edits_ and _add edits of your own_ to further clarify what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see this question as off topic, but to make that point, you may wish to _edit your question_ so that instead of saying "can someone please help?" you say "how can I design an electric circuit to solve this problem?".

Answer (score 1):

I would control the fan with a relay powered by the Air Conditioner AC circuit.

Comment: Wonder why I didn't think of this earlier. I guess thinking out of the box helps. Thanks! This should work.